# cordova requireCordovaModule() vs require()

Tags: node.js, cordova

What is the difference between `requireCordovaModule('fs')` and `require('fs')`?

Also, can `requireCordovaModules()` be used to require npm modules in the same way as `require()`?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova is a globally installed node module residing somewhere in your system like `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova`. Calling `requireCordovaModule()` means requiring a sub-module of Cordova in like `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules`.

The normal `require()` requires the `node_modules` from the calling node module.